# Apply rate based rules in serveless

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am using serverless and want to implement rate based rules to protect against basic ddos attacks.

I’ve been reading here https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/aws-announces-rate-based-rules-for-aws-waf/ and can see it within the Api gateway console

However there does not seem to be a way of adding this to serverless. I’ve looked through their docs but nothing

Is this possible to add in serverless?

Comment: See [How to associate a regional WAF with the AWS API Gateway used by your Serverless stack](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-associate-waf/). Are you asking specifically about how to configure some feature using serverless?

Comment: It seems close I’ll play around - doesn’t mention it’s the Ip rate limit

Comment: @JakeOwen Did you figure it out?